# Gephi - how to generate weight for edge thickness

Tags: excel, csv, gephi

I have a small amount of csv data counting connections between different countries, with only three cols, e.g.:

[image]

I can use this (about 100 rows) to create a nice network vis in gephi where node sizes can be resized on degree

However, ideally I'd like the edges to be weighted in size/thickness based on how many connections... e.g. in the image about UK and USA are connected twice, so their thickness would be twice the size of Greece and Nepal's connecting edge.

Is there any way to generate these weighting values automatically, either in gephi or in excel?

The one problem is that the countries are not in a standard order between source and target (e.g. USA and UK in the example above are in different orders, UK coming in the source column for one connection and USA coming first in the source column for the other connection).

Basically, I just need a way to auto count the node connections to make a value for each edge popularity/occurrence. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, did this with two helper columns using match():
[image]

So, edited based on the comments and countif() to count multiple ocurrences:

```
=COUNTIF(F$3:F$12,"="&CONCATENATE(B3,C3))+COUNTIF(F$3:F$12,"="&CONCATENATE(C3,B3))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting and potentially viable but I notice that cell D10 says '1' when shouldn't it be '2'? i.e. because UK-USA connection is present twice

Comment: I've tried this and it appears to only count to 2? i.e. 1 for connections with only one occurrence and 2 for connections with 2 *or more* ... some have 3, 4 or more etc.

Comment: Superstar! Thanks

Comment: @the_t_test_1 glad you like it, I'll have to see if I can do this without a visible helper column...must be a way. But as long as it works that's good.